# How does the Levenberge-Marquerdt algorithm work? Explained with some (simple?) examples if possible

Tags: least-squares, spheres, point-cloud

I am trying to understand nonlinear least squares to fit spheres in point cloud data. I kind of understand how the linear least squares works but every kind of paper on nonlinear least squares/Levenberge-Marquerdt is just pure magic to me. Well, it's more that I just don't understand that level of math.

I know that you can linearize(?) the sphere function to use linear least squares but the PCL implementation of a sphere fit uses Levenberge-Marquerdt, which is why I have to understand what I am using, if that makes sense.

If possible, can anyone make a small example on how to use the Levenberge-Marquerdt algorithm?

Comment: Do you mean the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm described at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm ?

Comment: @kimchilover Honest to god, I barely understand what the steps are exactly. "Standard" Least Squares is explained so much easier. I already read the wiki like 15 times now lol